# Word wrap in WebStorm

Tags: settings, webstorm, word-wrap

Which position in WebStorm settings responds for word wrap/line break? In VSCode it's easy: <kbd>Alt + Z</kbd>
When line is so long, and in code editor displays like:

```
1   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
    adipisicing elit. Blanditiis cumque debitis 
    deleniti distinctio dolor doloribus.
2   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
3   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

I used section `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Soft wraps`, but nothing changed.

Comment: Not sure what feature you are looking for. Is it about inserting line breaks when the line length exceeds certain value, or about visually wrapping the line without adding 'hard' breaks? The former can be configured in code styles preferences and should be set per language 9and even per statement in some cases). The latter is done by enabling soft wraps - line is auto-wrapped to fit the editor size

Comment: `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Soft wraps` sets the default behaviour. AFAIK it will not affect already opened files. Either close and re-open that file .. or change manually soft-wrap option for already opened file via menu.